# 20.04 LTS Turn off adaptive brightness on desktop

Tags: 20.04, brightness

When I have a brighter window open, the screen gets REALLY bright.

When I have a darker window open, the screen gets REALLY dark.

It has nothing to do with environmental light sources, as this is a desktop computer without a webcam.

The quick and constant changes in brightness are murdering my eyes. What could be causing this and how do I turn it off?

- OS: Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS
- GPU: Intel HD Graphics 5500
- CPU: Intel Core i3-5010U
- Monitor: TCL 50S425

Comment: I wonder how you turned on adaptive brightness in the first place. As far as I know, Ubuntu does not have such a feature by default. Is your monitor doing it?

Comment: I think you're right... apparently my monitor keeps separate settings for each input? And somehow the adaptive brightness got turned on, but only for the ubuntu input =/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was my display. I couldn't find an adaptive brightness setting in the general settings.. but it turns out my display keeps separate settings for each input with odd (to me anyway) naming conventions... and somehow the adaptive brightness got turned on, but only for the Ubuntu input >.>

It's now off, and I feel a bit silly and confused =/